# Ошибка в телеграм боте Python

Tags: python, telebot

```
menu_access_no = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
menu_access_no.add(
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Купить доступ', callback_data='buy_access'),  # +
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Профиль', callback_data='profile'),  # +
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Информаци', callback_data='access_no_info'),  # +
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Тех. Поддержка', callback_data='support_no')  # +
)

menu_access_yes = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
menu_access_yes.add(
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Профиль', callback_data='profile'),  # +
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Информация', callback_data='access_yes_info'),  # +
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Запросить выплату', callback_data='order_payout'),  # +
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Тех. Поддержка', callback_data='support_yes')  # -
)

menu_admin = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
menu_admin.add(
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Информация', callback_data='admin_info'),  # +
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Запросы на вывод', callback_data='admin_list_order_payment'),  # +
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Прибыль', callback_data='admin_profit'),  # +
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Выйти из админки', callback_data='go_main_menu')  # +
)

btn_close = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
btn_close.add(
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❌', callback_data='close')
)

menu_buy_access = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
menu_buy_access.add(
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=' Проверить оплату', callback_data='check_payment'),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Отменить покупку', callback_data='cancel_payment')
)

btn_back_to_admin_menu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
btn_back_to_admin_menu.add(
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Вернуться в админ меню', callback_data='back_to_admin_menu')
)

admin_order_info = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
admin_order_info.add(
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Удалить из списка', callback_data='del_order'),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Выйти', callback_data='back_to_admin_menu')
)
```

Вылезает ошибка после запуска файла main.py:

```
File "C:\Users\probo\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\Telegram bot  Пирамида, инвестиции\menu.py", line 3, in <module>
    menu_access_no = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'InlineKeyboardMarkup'
```

Comment: что такое types? Откуда оно берется?

Comment: from telebot import types первой строкой прописал, забыл скопировать

Answer (score 2):

По всей видимости где-то в вашем коде описана функция `types`:

```
def types(...):
```

И эта функция перекрывает импортируемый вами модуль `types`.